# Mongo append to standardized string field based on mapping of multiple fields (including nested)

Tags: python, arrays, mongodb, aggregation-framework, pymongo

I have a large collection with fields like:

```
{
    'class': 'apple'
},
{
    'class': 'appl'
},
{
    'class': 'orange',
    'nested': [
        {'classification': 'app'},
        {'classification': 'A',
        {'classification': 'orang'}
    ]
},
{
    'nested': [
        {'classification': 'O'},
        {'classification': 'unknown'}
    ]
}
```

I also have a Python dictionary mapping field values like:

```
{
    'class': {
        'apple': 'a',
        'appl': 'a',
        'orange': 'o'
    },
    'nested.classification': {
        'app': 'a',
        'A': 'a',
        'orang': 'o',
        'O': 'o',
        'unknown': 'u'
    }
}
```

I'm trying to (in PyMongo) update my MongoDB collection so that a string field of mapped characters is accumulated, from both the top-level `class` field and the nested `nested.classification` fields.

In the above, this would produce the following updates:

```
{
    'class': 'apple'
    'standard': 'a'
},
{
    'class': 'appl'
    'standard': 'a'
},
{
    'class': 'orange',
    'nested': [
        {'classification': 'app'},
        {'classification': 'A',
        {'classification': 'orang'}
    ]
    'standard': 'oaao'
},
{
    'nested': [
        {'classification': 'O'},
        {'classification': 'unknown'}
    ]
    'standard': 'ou'
}
```

How can I effectively do this at scale? Within an aggregation framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may get the desired result in 3 steps

**Note:** MongoDB can only iterate arrays, so we need to transform your dictionaries into `{k:"key", v: "value"}` array (we can use [$objectToArray](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/objectToArray/), but it's not worth it)

1. We map `class` field by iterating Python `class` dictionary
2. We map `nested classification` values by iterating Python `nested.classification` dictionary
3. We concat mapped values into a single value
4. (Optional) If you need to persist it, run `$merge` stage

**Disclamer:** MongoDB >=4.2 + I am not sure if this solution scales good

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$addFields": {
      standard: {
        $reduce: {
          input: [
            { k: "apple",  v: "a" },
            { k: "appl",   v: "a" },
            { k: "orange", v: "o" }
          ],
          initialValue: "",
          in: {
            $cond: [
              {
                $eq: ["$$this.k", "$class"]
              },
              "$$this.v",
              "$$value"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      standard: {
        $reduce: {
          input: {
            "$ifNull": [ "$nested", [] ]
          },
          initialValue: [ { v: "$standard" } ],
          in: {
            $concatArrays: [
              "$$value",
              {
                $filter: {
                  input: [
                    { k: "app",     v: "a" },
                    { k: "A",       v: "a" },
                    { k: "orang",   v: "o" },
                    { k: "O",       v: "o" },
                    { k: "unknown", v: "u" }
                  ],
                  as: "nested",
                  cond: {
                    $eq: [ "$$this.classification", "$$nested.k" ]
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "standard": {
        $reduce: {
          input: "$standard.v",
          initialValue: "",
          in: {
            "$concat": [ "$$value", "$$this" ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  //Optional - If you need to persist it
  { 
    $merge: {
      into: "collection",
      on: "_id",
      whenMatched: "replace"
    }
  }
])
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/zGIDXxiSOcQ)